# Is putting the small sized Rear tire for bike increase the mileage?

Tags: motorcycle, tires, wheels, direct-bikes

I heard that putting small sized rear tire increase the mileage is that true?
if true how does it makes difference than putting big sized tired to bike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinner the tyre, lesser the friction with the ground,so lesser energy to move the vehicle and so better mileage. 
However....it is not recommended, the bike manufacturers will not recommend to move to thinner tyres as bikes are only tested with the stock supplies and insurance companies may not accept any claims incase of any accident

Comment: It will also have an impact on handling and grip.

Comment: Also less rotating mass, so takes less energy to get up to speed.

Comment: I'm not getting why my question has been down voted? Please can you put comments